# update zip and state based on ip address

Tags: php, forms, ip

I have two fields:

```
<input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value="" />
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option value="XX">Outside USA/Canada</option>
  <option value="AL" selected>Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

I want to have zip code and state selected based on ip address of visitor.
its means everytime use visit this page in zip code filed there should be zip of visitor (based on ip) and state selected (based on ip)..

We can use some javascript function onload event of body or something like this, I am not sure. What may be the best way to do this?

Comment: The IP address isn't 100% accurate. You'll have trouble pin pointing the exact location

Comment: You'll probably want a geolocation service. Have you seen this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a user's ZIP code and city based on their IP using [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/developers/php).

Comment: This method is *extremely* unreliable.

Comment: @Pekka This seems like just a vanity feature, so I don't think it's crucial that it might be off once in a while.

Comment: I would usually agree, but I think having a form pre-filled with values from the next big city could be pretty annoying for a customer from a more rural area. The hits are often *so* far off... at least here in Germany

Comment: IP2Location is really great.but database seems too small.i just tested it but its showing "This field is not supported in DB1. Please upgrade your IP2Location database." for almost every field.but its really great to work with for some application.

Answer (score 2):

> i want to have zip code and state selected based on ip address of visitor.

Forget it. It is *sometimes* possible to detect the city based on the visitor's IP address, but more often than not, it is not. Especially in rural areas, or border regions where the nearest major city is in a different zip code and maybe even *state*, your results will be near useless.

You can consider using [HTML 5 geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo), but it needs the user's consent and it seems overkill to use this just to pre-fill some address fields.

Comment: Not only does it require consent, but it also requires JavaScript to be enabled, and displays no sort of notification about that if it's disabled.

Comment: @Pekka I like how you rip off other people's answers and pass them off as your own!

Comment: @PaulTwo people having the same idea at the same time is perfectly normal on these sites.

Comment: True, except you added your link after @Marcus AND linked to the exact same spot. But, I guess it was just a coincidence.

Comment: @Paul If you had taken a moment to research before making your accusation, you might have found that the link is the #1 result when Googling `html 5 geolocation`. Consider thinking a bit next time before pointing the finger like that; I take pride in contributing only original content to these sites, and to give credit where I borrow from others.

Comment: Oh no,
you all are really doing great.i am learning lot things from you peoples.its a great forum where everyone is learning and i love to spend time here instead of facebook..

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps have an AJAX call to a service like http://ipcim.com/en/?p=where, parse through the page in PHP, get the info that you need, and then fill in the text field and select box using Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: This method is *extremely* unreliable.

Comment: here i am just getting info on that page.but unable to use them on my website or some page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [geolocation API built into HTML 5](http://html5demos.com/geo). Have you considered that?

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [IP 2 Location](http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db11-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone) for few years. So far, the data seems accurate to us.

Comment: IP 2 Location didn't always provide the right results. Neither did Cloudflare's automatic option. So we built our own: https://www.completeapi.com which gathers data from various sources and has proven way more accurate. It's also not FREE, but new users get 1000 free queries. So at least you can test it and see if it will work for you.